# I don't know why this is not printing the way I think it should

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range

This is for a homework assignment, we were asked to write a for loop that starts at the beginning of a user inputted string and then print every 2nd letter

I have tried to add a new line but that didn't solve the issue. I have tried to do it without using the range function by using 
`for char in s:` and that produces the same results as using the range function

```
s = input('Please enter a string: ')

for i in range(len(s)):


    print(i, s[0::2].upper())
```

If the word was Testing it should print out like this

```
T

S


I

G
```

with every letter capitalized. It wouldn't be double spaced I just had to format it look right on here. My code will pick up every 2nd letter but it prints it all out on one line instead of printing it out individually and then prints out TSIG 7 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is probably what you want.

INPUT:

```
s = raw_input('Please enter a string: ')
s=s[0::2].upper()
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Please enter a string: TESTING
T
S
I
G
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = 'testing'

for i in s[::2]:
    print(i)
```

Your issue is that you are printing `s[0::2].upper()` every loop, and it is not affected by `i`: